# wix get version of external msi

Tags: wix

Is there a possibility to get the version of an external msi-file?

I have a bundle where I define to install several external MSI-files. One of these MSI files could be already installed on the target machine, which is why I want to add an InstallCondition where I check if the related MSI is already installed with a newer version. I know that this could be usually done with the bootstrapper, but we have a company-owned bootstrapper who can't do this. My current code looks like the following:

```
<util:ProductSearch UpgradeCode="GUID-C3AE7D89" Variable="InstalledServicesVersion" />

...
 <MsiPackage Vital="yes" EnableFeatureSelection="no" DisplayInternalUI="no" Visible="yes"
              Name="Services.msi"
              SourceFile="$(var.TargetDir)\Services.msi"
              Cache="yes"
              InstallCondition="(CurrentServicesVersion > InstalledServicesVersion)">
```

Well, how do I set CurrentServicesVersion, so that I can skip this MSI-file?
Or is there a better way of doing this (except bootstrapper)?